# How to Use a Global Variable in another File

Tags: python, variables, global-variables

I have a global variable that's declared inside a function in the functions.py file and I want to access this global variable in the main.py file. How do I achieve that?

```
# functions.py
def someFunction():
    global someVariable



#main.py
from functions import *
someVariable=0
```

Answer (score 0):

importing module with * gives access to all variables and functions in the current file. This should be working. Please tell me where you are facing a problem in this.

Comment: I get this error: NameError: name 'someVariable' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

`someVariable` is defined in `someFunction()`.

If you haven't called `someFunction()`, so the `someVariable` is undefined.

You can do this:

in main.py

```
#main.py
from functions import *
someFunction()
someVariable = 0
```

**or** in functions.py

```
# functions.py

someVariable = 0
```

Comment: I don't want to call the function in main.py because it has other code that I don't want to execute, and I also don't want to assign the variable a value in functions.py; I want to do this in main.py. I'm sorry, I should've mentioned in the post that this is not the real code but just an example for what I want to do. Also, I have a question: why can't I use the variable although it's global? I mean, I can use it without calling the function because it's global, so why's that not the case?

Comment: yes it's global， but that is after the function is called. Only when the function is called, the statement `global someVariable` executes

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you can do is intstead of declaring it inside function declare it as function attribute like shown below

```py
# functions.py

def someFunction():
    #your code
```

```py
# main.py

from functions import *

setattr(someFunction,'key_name',0) # this is how u set the value
someVariable = getattr(someFunction,'key_name') # this is how u access it
```

**But** if real code is not Possible please give a much clearer example code so that we can help you debug the exact problem